# Multiples Order BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola estoy teniendo problemas con un Stored Procedure en MSSql en el cual estoy tratando de ordenar los registros segun la columna que pida el usuario

```
DECLARE @SortType CHAR, @SortBy VARCHAR(50)
SET @SortType = 'A'
SET @SortBy = '#Pedido'

SELECT 
[#Pedido],
[Largo de hoja],
[Cantidad de hojas],
[Salidas],
[Fecha agregado],
[Fecha termino],
[Estado]
FROM Order_Completed
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @SortType='A'THEN
        CASE 
            WHEN @SortBy='#Pedido' THEN [#Pedido]
            WHEN @SortBy='Largo de hoja' THEN [Largo de hoja]
            WHEN @SortBy='Cantidad de hojas' THEN [Cantidad de hojas]
            WHEN @SortBy='Salidas' THEN [Salidas]
            WHEN @SortBy='Fecha' THEN [Fecha agregado]
        END
    END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @SortType='D'THEN
        CASE 
            WHEN @SortBy='#Pedido' THEN [#Pedido]
            WHEN @SortBy='Largo de hoja' THEN [Largo de hoja]
            WHEN @SortBy='Cantidad de hojas' THEN [Cantidad de hojas]
            WHEN @SortBy='Salidas' THEN [Salidas]
            WHEN @SortBy='Fecha' THEN [Fecha agregado]
        END
    END DESC;
```

funciona bien, excepto en este caso en especifico, la columna #Pedido es de tipo VARCHAR mientras que el resto a excepción de las fechas, son FLOAT, esto es lo que devuelve la consulta:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Si quito la columna de fecha  de la consulta del ORDER BY devuelve esto:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 22
> Error converting data type varchar to float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `CASE` debe ser consistente en el dato que retorna, tu problema es básicamente este:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN 'EJEMPLO' ELSE 1.0 END

Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

Es decir, el `CASE` podría eventualmente retornar una cadena o un valor numérico, lo cual no es aceptable y termina generando el error.
Podrías normalizar el dato:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), 'EJEMPLO') ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), 1.0) END
```

Pero eso puede traerte otros problemas con el orden cuando se trate de datos numéricos o fecha. Lo que podrías hacer es escribir múltiples ordenes e invalidarlos cuando no es el que buscas. La prueba de concepto sería algo así:

```
DECLARE @OrderBy    VARCHAR(200) = 'id'

SELECT  *
    FROM sysobjects sc
    ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'name' THEN name ELSE NULL END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'id' THEN id ELSE NULL END ASC
```

En tu caso, pordría ser algo así:

```
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @SortType='A'THEN AND @SortBy='#Pedido' THEN [#Pedido] ELSE NULL END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @SortType='A'THEN AND @SortBy='Largo de hoja' THEN [Largo de hoja] ELSE NULL END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @SortType='A'THEN AND @SortBy='Cantidad de hojas' THEN [Cantidad de hojas] ELSE NULL END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @SortType='A'THEN AND @SortBy='Salidas' THEN [Salidas] ELSE NULL END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @SortType='A'THEN AND @SortBy='Fecha' THEN [Fecha agregado] ELSE NULL END ASC
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, la solucion funciono! Saludos.